# Having trouble with Bilingual URLs

Tags: localization, url, language

I'm in the midst of setting up a bilingual website. English and Welsh.

I have set up the locales in my settings (en and cy_gb)

My directories have the necessary folders for each language, with each containing their respective index.php and htaccess files.

Craft's general config file is changed. Basically I have followed the steps in the Craft docs. My site loads and clicking links loads them fine, but when I add a cy to the URL, I get a Craft 404 page

Is there anything I maybe missing? Do I need to add something to the templates themselves? Any help would be appreciated.

**General config**

```
return array(
// Base site URL
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'https://site.domain.net/',
    'cy_gb' => 'https://site.domain.net/cy/'

),
```

**/cy_gb/index.php**

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

//Tell Craft to serve the Welsh content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'cy_gb');
```

**/en/index.php**

```
// Path to your craft/ folder
$craftPath = '../../craft';

//Tell Craft to serve the English content
define('CRAFT_LOCALE', 'en');
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you posted looks like you should change `/cy_gb/index.php` to `/cy/index.php`. `/cy/` is the actual subfolder you are requesting here: `https://site.domain.net/cy/`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply, but I finally figured out the issue. It was a permissions problem on the .htaccess in the cy folder. I deleted the one in there and uploaded a fresh one and it all seemed to slot into place.